# CSS Border on top of background image (same div?)

Tags: css, html, background, border

I've been struggling for hours to try and get this simple border to appear on top of a div of a set height, but it's just not happening. I've checked out z-indexing and ':after', but nothing seems to be working.

The content's parent is: (establishes the content to be in the middle of the page)

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top: 50px;
    width:800px;
}
```

The content is then filled by the div-class "greycontent":

```
.greycontent {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
height: 350px;
background: url(images/stacked_circles.png) repeat;
}
```

The area that is now covered by the background URL attempts to contain a border (away from edges):

```
.fill {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
}
```

It just won't work. If my description was unclear, this image should clear up what I'm trying to convey:

[image]

Thank you!

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jenqh/1/)

Comment: Can you put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Could you post your HTML markup as well? or as @Adrift said as I'm typing this, a fiddle?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that now.

Comment: "away from edges" part is not clear to me..

Comment: Sorry if I am being unclear - by away from edges I mean not a border which sits right at the edge of the 800px and 350px width defined by the parent element, rather there is a margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your trying to achieve? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msfy9/2/)**

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50px;
    width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#ccc;
    width:800px;
}
.greycontent {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 350px;
    width:350px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:0 auto 60px;
}
```

Updated your **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jenqh/4/)**.

Comment: That definitely achieves the desired effect visually, so thank you for that, however my problem is that the 'content' parent element in my full source is comprised of several child elements, therefore there is no overall background to establish in the parent, rather I was trying to achieve one div to set a blue background and another to put a border within this blue background. Should I add another divclass within the grey content div class? Thanks again!

Comment: I am a little unclear by what you mean. From my understanding, is this what you mean? **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jenqh/7/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you do not want to put a `::before` or `::after` elements, **you can simply use the `background-clip` property**.

```css
.myDiv {
     background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Exemple: https://codepen.io/geekschool/pen/JBdpdj